# Help needed: DocStrip with multiple files

Tags: docstrip

I am maintaining a bunch of files, presenting packages and classes for my university corporate design.  In order to use literate programming and have better documentation, I am playing around with `DocStrip`.  I was able to build the necessary basic `.ins`-file and a `.dtx`-file.  I could build an useless `sample.sty` from the `.dtx` as well as a readable documentation from the same source.

I plan, to split the code of my packages and classes onto several `.dtx`-sources, as a lot of code is identical in one or another resulting file.

I especially would love to have a dedicated `version.dtx` file, which should be included in every package and class, DocStrip shall create.  I intend to have a unique version info from the "package release date" in every single derived style and class.

What would be the best way?  Is there any tutorial, that shows this trick?

Trying to set a LaTeX-Variable in the `.ins`-file did not work, as the macro was not expanded.

Here is my `sample.ins`:

```
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\preamble
Project Sample Test -- Versuche mit einer oder mehreren DTX-Dateien
\endpreamble
\usedir{tex/latex/sample}
%%% DOES NOT WORK!
%%% Define a version for all subsequent generated files
\def\TUC@Version{2017/02/05 v0.01a}
\generate{\file{sample.sty}{\from{sample.dtx}{package}}}
```

And this is the stripped down `sample.dtx`:

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
Project Sample Test -- Versuche mit einer oder mehreren DTX-Dateien
% \fi
% \iffalse
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2005/12/01]
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{sample}
%<package>    [\TUC@Version (Test with DocStrip)]
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{sample}

\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges

\begin{document}
  \DocInput{sample.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \Finale
%
\endinput
```

Comment: there shouldn't be any problem to include a version.dtx (but your code attempted setting that in an ins file which is also doable but different) see for example format.ins which includes multiple dtx including ltvers.dtx to make latex.ltx

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for the hint.  The `\def` in the `.ins`-file was just try -- and desaster :-)

Comment: Just wanted to say this question and David's answer is one of the most ingenious things I've discovered here and will help me maintain my own packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**smpl.ins**

```
\input docstrip

\generate{
 \file{pack1.sty}{
  \from{pack1.dtx}{package1}
  \from{vers.dtx}{}
  \from{pack1.dtx}{package}
}}

\generate{
 \file{pack2.sty}{
  \from{pack2.dtx}{package1}
  \from{vers.dtx}{}
  \from{pack2.dtx}{package}
}}


\endbatchfile
```

**vers.dtx**

```
%    \begin{macrocode}
2017/02/05 v1.0
%    \begin{macrocode}
```

**pack1.dtx**

```
% \iffalse
%<package1>\ProvidesPackage{pack1}[%
%<package>pack1 package]
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{pack1}
\GetFileInfo{pack1.sty}
\begin{document}
\title{The \textsf{pack1} package\thanks{This file
        has version number \fileversion, last
        revised \filedate.}}
\author{me}
\date{\filedate}
\maketitle
\DocInput{pack1.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \StopEventually{}
%
% \begin{macro}{\foo}
%  A really useful command
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
\def\foo{bar}
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \Finale
%
```

**pack2.dtx**

```
% \iffalse
%<package1>\ProvidesPackage{pack2}[%
%<package>pack2 package]
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{pack2}
\GetFileInfo{pack2.sty}
\begin{document}
\title{The \textsf{pack2} package\thanks{This file
        has version number \fileversion, last
        revised \filedate.}}
\author{me}
\date{\filedate}
\maketitle
\DocInput{pack2.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \StopEventually{}
%
% \begin{macro}{\bar}
%  A really useful command
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
\def\bar{foo}
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \Finale
%
```

Then a command such as

```
tex smpl.ins
```

will generate `pack1.sty` and `pack2.sty`, with `pack1.sty` looking like

```
%%
%% This is file `pack1.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% pack1.dtx  (with options: `package1')
%% vers.dtx 
%% pack1.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% 
%% IMPORTANT NOTICE:
%% 
%% For the copyright see the source file.
%% 
%% Any modified versions of this file must be renamed
%% with new filenames distinct from pack1.sty.
%% 
%% For distribution of the original source see the terms
%% for copying and modification in the file pack1.dtx vers.dtx pack1.dtx.
%% 
%% This generated file may be distributed as long as the
%% original source files, as listed above, are part of the
%% same distribution. (The sources need not necessarily be
%% in the same archive or directory.)
\ProvidesPackage{pack1}[%
2017/02/05 v1.0
pack1 package]
\def\foo{bar}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `pack1.sty'.
```

and `pack2.sty` not looking that different.

```
pdflatex pack1.dtx will make
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU David.  I think, I got now the trick.  `smpl.ins` will extract via guard `<package1>`the string `\ProvidesPackage{...}[`, than the naked version number is inserted from file `vers.dtx` and after that, a second run on the package `pack1.dtx` is run, this time with the guard `<package>`.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL take them out the iffalse and put them in a `macrocode` but they are not very informative typeset with no date